# Iostream issue on codeblocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, iostream

I get a huge error list. It points to the included iostream and every instance of the term "Operator"
This happens anytime I compile anything more complicated than a simple "Hello World"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhskX.png]

Comment: Those huge error lists are a trademark of C++. Things cascade.

Comment: why does this question have a 'C' tag?  suggest removing the 'C' tag

Answer (score 5):

You are doing `cin >> endl` which makes no sense. There is no overload of [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) which would match these types. [`cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) is an `std::istream` object and none of the overloads accept something whose type matches with that of [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl).

If you want to take input of type `T`, where `T` is one of the [fundamental data types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) you can simply say

```
T inp;
cin >> inp;
```

Comment: `endl` inserts a new line (`\n`) and then flushes the `ostream`. I think he just wants to insert a new line after reading from cin. Which can be achieved through `cin >> blah; cout << endl;`

Comment: Thanks so much. That fixed a very simple situation.